# Cors configuration with camel

Tags: rest, cors, apache-camel

I have an AJAX request to my Rest Webservice with a custom Header "login".

Here is my rest configuration :

```
restConfiguration()
.component("netty4-http")
.bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json)
.dataFormatProperty("prettyPrint", "true")
.enableCORS(true)
.corsAllowCredentials(true)
.corsHeaderProperty("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, login")
.contextPath(contextPath).host(host).port(port);
```

I'm getting a 200 response to the OPTIONS preflight request but the "login" Header is not the Access-Control-Allow-Headers and my browser never send the actual request.

Also i have not done any configuration in my route for cors.

Here is my request headers

> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:58.0)
>   Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0
>
> Accept:
>   text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
>
> Accept-Language: fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
>
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
>
> Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
>
> Access-Control-Request-Headers: login
>
> Origin: http://127.0.0.1:8081
>
> DNT: 1
>
> Connection: keep-alive

And responce headers :

> content-length: 0
>
> Accept:
>   text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
>
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
>
> Accept-Language: fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With,
>   Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method,
>   Access-Control-Request-Headers
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE,
>   OPTIONS, CONNECT, PATCH
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://127.0.0.1:8081
>
> Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
>
> Access-Control-Request-Headers: login
>
> Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
>
> breadcrumbId: ID-resitt-ws-1521624297667-0-6
>
> DNT: 1
>
> Origin: http://127.0.0.1:8081
>
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:58.0)
>   Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0
>
> connection: keep-alive (modifié)

I feel like my cors configuration doesn't change anything to my situation.

Comment: What version of Camel do you use, and have you tried with latest version

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We found an answer, `.enableCORS(true)` must be placed after `.contextPath(contextPath).host(host).port(port)` line.

like this

```
restConfiguration()
.component("netty4-http")
.bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json)
.dataFormatProperty("prettyPrint", "true")
.contextPath(contextPath).host(host).port(port)
.enableCORS(true)
.corsAllowCredentials(true)
.corsHeaderProperty("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, login");
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the CORS headers wheren't in http response when the camel thrown an exception and returned a 500 error.